# using if statement to check for text value

Tags: google-sheets-query

in google sheets im trying to do a formula that first checks if there is text in a cell elsewhere on the page example:

A1 contains text = true then C1/B1 output to D1

A1 contains text = false then D1 = 0

reason im using this is im pulling values from a 2nd sheet using a drop down and populating the results on page 1 but when there is no data to pull for d1 it flags an error #DIV/0! but it has to try pull these rows of data as some data will use the rows.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Put this in D1:

```
=IF(A1="",C1/B1,0)
```